# Limiting access for Form Library when using InfoPath 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

I recently developed an InfoPath version of my company's performance management tool using info path.  To limit access to the form, I added a restricted view page that runs thru form load rules that if you are not the user, manager or supervisor, you are shown this page.  Authenticating the employee is easy, a simple rule captures his/her user name when they submit the form.  The Manager and Supervisor are pulled from a custom list after they are selected from a drop down as part of our admin data.

My problem is that depending on where they are logging in from, the username may not match what is pulled from the custom list.  Some days it is all lower case (fname.lname) and others it is sentence case (Fname.Lname).

Any idea why this is happening or a better way to restrict access to the actual Form Library.  I need the three to be able to access the form throughout the rating period, but no one elses.  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use SharePoint permissions to control access to the Forms library?

Comment: In order to fill a form, an employee must have "contribute" rights.  If they have contribute rights, they can view all forms and not just their own.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default view of the library to the filter "Created equals [Me]". Remove all other views and don't permit users to create custom views for the library. This way, SharePoint will only serve the documents the user has created. SharePoint will work with the authentication that is used to open the site. Case of a user name should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

- First assign the permission for the document library for managers and supervisors access.
- Then use the rule for individual item as "Created equals [Me]"
  That's it. It'll work as per your expectation.